# CREATE, INSERT INTO & UPDATE vs CREATE & SELECT

Tags: postgresql

I'm writing a big sql script in PostgreSQL (Netezza) and I would like to define the best strategy to create and update a [table] from another [ext_table]. As you can see, some fields (bi, i=1...n) are calculated from the source fields (ai, i=1...n) with conditions using `CASE`. Which is more efficient and why?

1) Create, insert and then update:

```
CREATE TABLE <table> (a1,a2,a3,...b1,b2,b3...);
INSERT INTO [table] (a1,a2,a3,...) SELECT a1,a2,a3,... FROM [ext_table];
UPDATE [table] SET 
b1=CASE WHEN a1=1 THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END,
b2=CASE WHEN a2='A' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,
b3=CASE WHEN a2='Y' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END;
```

2) Create and populate while selecting:

```
CREATE TABLE [table] AS (
SELECT a1,a2,a3,...,
(CASE WHEN a1=1 THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END) as b1,
(CASE WHEN a2='A' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as b2,
(CASE WHEN a2='Y' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as b3,
....
FROM [ext_table]
);
```

Comment: The second one will be more efficient because you only write the data **once** and in the first statement you write it **twice** (btw: the parentheses around the select in the second statement are useless)

Comment: Correct answer 3) SELECT INTO
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-selectinto.html

Comment: Scratch that I am incorrect: "CREATE TABLE AS is functionally similar to SELECT INTO. CREATE TABLE AS is the recommended syntax, since this form of SELECT INTO is not available in ECPG or PL/pgSQL, because they interpret the INTO clause differently. Furthermore, CREATE TABLE AS offers a superset of the functionality provided by SELECT INTO."